# Implications of Failing N95 Fit Test During COVID-19 Pandemic?

Tags: united-states, employment, health, covid-19

I am a Registered Nurse and have documented evidence in my NY hospital that I failed the N95 fit test for years. What are my rights surrounding this and the COVID-19 epidemic? I have a NIOSH compliant full face respirator mask that I can wear.

Can I be legally be denied wearing the full face respirator if I previously failed the N95 fit test?

What are the salary implications if I reveal to administration that I failed the fit test?

Am I legally responsible to reveal this information to them?

Comment: Most hospitals have a procedure for a staff member who cannot wear a N95 for whatever reason, they wear a PAPR for example. This is in "normal" times, saw with a patient with TB. Is your hospital declining to allow that, or are you just checking before asking them? Your salary question is off-topic here but the answer is generally no difference. Legally responsible to reveal? At this time it is probably in your best safety interest to get it cleared up.

Comment: I am just checking before asking. Can they request I do not work if they are unable to provide a PAPR (or equal substitute)?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer. In normal times, if they did they would run up against Joint Commission, OSHA, and NY state laws. I can't say what is happening in real-time on the ground at a time where some hospitals don't even have enough N95's.